# Using xpath and selenium to select a HTML element in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Thanks for letting me ask my questions here. I am new to Selenium and XPath, just trying to scrape a not-so-simple website using Python.

My questions are:

1. Do you have an answer to my specific question on how to select the HTML element in question?
2. Do you have any addition to the learning ressources I listed below (which seem very helpful, but I was seemingly not yet advanced enough to apply them to my situation)?

The specific question: I have a HTML file that looks as follows and want to extract the 'data-testid="qs-select-make"' element (in the end, I want to use selenium to update the drop-down menu)

For the life of me, I do not get it to work....

```
<div class = "a">
<div class = "ab">
<div class = "abc">
<div class = "abcd">
<select class="tya6p HaBLt A4yQa q0MnL" placeholder="Any" data-testid="qs-select- 
make"><option selected="" value="">Any</option>
```

Using the google chrome web developer I already found the "correct" (albeit not very nice path) seems to be
`[@id="root"]/div/div/article[1]/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/select`

Still, the following code, attempting to insert the make "Audi" into the drop-down menu, fails with an Invalid Selector Exception:

```
make_string = "//select[//* 
[@id='root"]/div/div/article[1]/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/select]option 
selected[text()='{}']".format("Audi") 

driver.find_element("xpath", make_string).click() #use selenium to click the button
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, and of a nicer way to do it?

Regarding question 2, the resource. So far I have used:

- Stackoverflow, helpful as always, in particular [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808909/selecting-an-element-with-xpath-and-selenium)
- A very useful testsigma blogpost, which pointed me towards the chrome browser web developer to at least the the path:[here](https://testsigma.com/blog/xpath-in-selenium/)
- The Selenium documentation - very nicely written, but since I am beginner I am not yet able to apply the general concepts to my specific issue... apologies: [Here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/)

Comment: For an accurate search, you need a link to the site.

Comment: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html, https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/support_features/select_lists/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below `xpath` to identify the element. Please add `syncronisation` time as well.

```
driver.find_element("xpath", "//select[@data-testid='qs-select-make']//option[text()='{}']".format("Audi")).click()
```

Comment: Thank you this works! One small question: Any pointers towards beginner resources on this topic? It seems so easy, but is so niche that I don't know where to start

Comment: This is based on your best practices. your search in google `xpath` Cheat sheet or how to learn xpath, you will definitely get loads of option to study. You can refer this as well --> https://devhints.io/xpath and https://www.browserstack.com/guide/xpath-locators-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression has syntax errors, making it an invalid selector. To select the select element with data-testid="qs-select-make", you can use a cleaner and more direct XPath expression. Here is the correct way to do it:

```py
make_selector = "//select[@data-testid='qs-select-make']"

driver.find_element_by_xpath(make_selector).click()

option_xpath = f"{make_selector}/option[text()='Audi']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(option_xpath).click()
```

This code first selects the dropdown by its data-testid attribute, then clicks it to expand the options, and finally selects the "Audi" option from the expanded dropdown list.

Comment: Thank you this works! Pity I cannot accept two answers.
 One small question (same as below): Any pointers towards beginner resources on this topic? It seems so easy, but is so niche that I don't know where to start

Comment: I would say that to get better at Selenium, the best resource would be the Pythn-specific documentation: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: Also, when writing XPATH expressions, look into writing them in the DevTools console using $x(''), It allows you to test the expressions while writing them!

Comment: Thank you! Especially the DevTools console hint is likely going to be worth gold!